# Iterate through nested arrays of objects with an undetermined number of children node levels

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a *multi-node tree*, when I add a new row, I need to get the reference of that row, by its id, to fire the rowclick event programmatically.

In the following example, if I add the row with id 9, how to iterate through the tree to this node.

Note: children of children nodes are unlimited (for example: parent-children-children-children-children-children... )

Tree example

```
let data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent 1"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": " parent 2",
    "children": [{
        "id": 5,
        "name": "parent-children 5",
    },{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "parent-children 6",
        "children": [{
            "id": 7,
            "name": "parent-children-children 7",
        },{
            "id": 8,
            "name": "parent-children-children 8",
            "children": [{
                "id": 9,
                "name": "parent-children-children-children 9",
            },{
                "id": 10,
                "name": "parent-children-children-children 10",
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "parent 3"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "parent 4"
}]
```

Iteration on levels one and two of the nodes

```
getItemRow(id){
    //If is a parent node
    let myItem = this.parents.find(parent => parent.id === id);
    if(myItem !== undefined){ return myItem }

    //If is a second level children node (parent-children)
    this.parents.forEach(function(parent){
        let child = parent.children.find(child => child.id === id);
        if(child !== undefined){ return child }

    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a recursive function?

Comment: The data result from a laravel recursive query.
On the client side, despite several attempts, I still haven't found a specific solution for this case of getting the row's position in the tree by id. I would appreciate suggestions to implement a recursive function for this purpose.

Comment: Willow has what looks like a good solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can recursively search all nodes until we find the match:

```js
getItemRow(id){
    return findNodeWithId(id, this.parents)
}

findNodeWithId(id, rootArr) {
  for (let el of rootArr) {
    if (el.id === id) {
      return el
    }
    if (el.children) {
        const idFoundInChildren = findNodeWithId(id, el.children)
        if (idFoundInChildren !== null) {
          return idFoundInChildren
        }
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursion and find the object directly or by searching the children array.

```js
const
    find = (array, id) => {
        let result;
        array.some(o => result = o.id === id
            ? o
            : find(o.children || [], id)
        )
        return result;
    },
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "parent 1" }, { id: 2, name: " parent 2", children: [{ id: 5, name: "parent-children 5" }, { id: 6, name: "parent-children 6", children: [{ id: 7, name: "parent-children-children 7" }, { id: 8, name: "parent-children-children 8", children: [{ id: 9, name: "parent-children-children-children 9" }, { id: 10, name: "parent-children-children-children 10" }] }] }] }, { id: 3, name: "parent 3" }, { id: 4, name: "parent 4" }];

console.log(find(data, 9));
```

Comment: Thanks Willow and Nina